# Windows Phone 8 app submission

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

The Windows Phone 8 app submission dashboard/portal has to be one of the most confusing sites I have dealt with compared to Android/iOS (and the least documented). I have two questions I was hoping someone can help me with:

When uploading a new version of the app with a new version number (containing just functionality changes/bug fixes, no changes to the package itself), I click the app I would like to update in the Windows Phone Store Developer Center and then click "Update app" which is fine and that creates the update package in the Dev Center.

[image: update_app]

I then go to "Complete" under Current submission:

[image: complete_submission]

And then finally, "Upload and describe your package(s)":

[image: upload_packages]

This is where I get thrown off a little, if I want to upload a new version of the app (no changes in the package, just functionality changes as described) then do I click "Replace" or "Add New"?

I have my suspicions I need to click "Replace" since I will essentially be replacing an old version with a new.

But I do that, upload my new package but the Windows Phone 8 Dev Center does not seem to pick up any new details about my XAP - and I cannot work out the reason why. One way I have verified this, is the Package version number remains the same as the old one:

[image: app_version]

Is what I am doing the correct process? Is the behaviour I am seeing expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you Replace your new xap file with old one, Are you submitting other Details again ? when you Upload any new xap file, you needed to fill all details and images again.

Comment: you can add new xap or replace existing but ultimately it would replace old with new in both cases. You would be able to see your new version when you are Proceeding to Submission, at that time you can see all xaps that you have submitted with version number

Comment: When I "Replace", I don't want to resubmit all other Details again - but they are wiped and I am forced to. I would have thought the Dev Center would retain the details for the newer version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two scenarios:

**Update WP8 version of app (e.g. from 1.5.0.0 to 1.6.0.0)**

All you need to do to update a package is to **Replace** the old one. This will keep all the details and screenshots that you previously entered intact, so you just need to enter the details (if you want) for the update (below app description). Also don't forget to update the version number of the package, but even if you don't, the use will still get notified that there is an update.

**Update a WP8 version to add specific WP8.1 features for phones that have WP8.1**

Now since you don't want to publish a completely different app with the same name and everything, you just need to add a new package to the same app. So now you will have two packages to maintain under the same app, first one is the WP8 version, and the second one is the WP8.1 version. Then if you just want to update, let's say the 8.1 version, you just replace that package with a new 8.1 package.

If you feel like supporting WP7 as well, you add a new package for WP7 as well. So depending on which OS your user currently is, the store will manage which version of your package the user will get.

**NOTE:**

There are some special cases where multiple packages of the same version (example WP8) are uploaded, but the difference between them is the main languages. Example for games where you need custom language-bound assets, you want to keep the size of the package small, and you can't tackle the problem with just resource strings, you can upload different packages for different languages.

Comment: Thanks @Ertay! Scenario 1 (updating from 1.5.0.0 to 1.6.0.0) is the scenario I require. However, the entered details/description and screenshots seem to be deleting from the Dev Center App Description page when I do; is there any reason for this?

Comment: One additional question, is the Package version number meant to be obtained from the newly uploaded xap package? Or is this meant to be manually typed every time?

Comment: @keldar That's quite strange. I just tested it here, and it preserves everything. Before pressing Replace, try Saving first, it should return you to the previous page. Then go to Upload packages again and try replacing, see if that helps.

_EDIT_ You need to manually enter the package number, it does not grab it from the package.

Comment: Thanks so much Ertay - this has proved invaluable. I think the Dev Center was having a moment as it's now retaining the information! Marked as the answer too. Thanks!

Comment: For those who don't see the 'replace' button: you have to use IE. it doesn't work under firefox.